# Trigger for span text/html on changed

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-events

Is there any event in jQuery or JavaScript that triggered when `span` tag text/html has been changed ?

Code:

```
<span class="user-location"> </span>

$('.user-location').change(function () {
    //Not working
});
```

Comment: What do you mean with "change"? When the innerHtml changes?

Comment: `span` is not input element ,so there will be nothing changed until you have changed ! S

Comment: I just want to event when on span text has been changed ?

Comment: @GovindSamrow does my answer not solve your problem? It's done only with Javascript, no special libraries. Or do you need a better solution?

Comment: Its working but I'm waiting for something very simple.

Comment: @GovindSamrow I added a jQuery example, it is even shorter (if you dont count the _simulate Change Code_).

Comment: @GovindSamrow I would like to improve my future answers, thats' why I would like ask some questions, why didn't you accept my answer which had the solution posted 6 hours before the one you finally accepted? To much text? should the Updates be at the begin of the answer? or should the Updates be better highlighted?

Comment: Sorry about that but answer two much lengthy and It will confuse future coming users. Its not about points.

Comment: @GovindSamrow thanks for the feedback, I will try to keep my future answer precise and concise. _(My question had  nothing to do with the points, I just want to improve my answering skills)_

Answer (score 38, accepted):

you can use `DOMSubtreeModified` to track changes on your span element i.e(if text of your span element changes dynamically ).

```
$('.user-location').on('DOMSubtreeModified',function(){
  alert('changed')
})
```

check out the followinf link https://jsbin.com/volilewiwi/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Watch out because MutationEvents are deprecated: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Mutation_events, use MutationObserver instead https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver

Comment: you are a genius

Comment: You are a life saver. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 13):

The **short answer** is for **jQuery** with the `change`-Event is, **NO**,

> This event is limited to **input** elements, **textarea** boxes and
> **select** elements. For select boxes, checkboxes, and radio buttons,
> the event is fired immediately when the user makes a selection with
> the mouse, but for the other element types the event is deferred until
> the element loses focus. ... *here is a link to the documentation https://api.jquery.com/change/*

**But** with something like the `MutationsObserver` here the link to the MDN Reference https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver , you could watch for changes in the DOM. In your specific case the `span` in question.

**Here an brief example (adapted from the MDN Reference)**
*In the Example the `span` change is simulated with a `setTimeout`*

```js
  // select the target node
var target = document.getElementById('user-location');
 
// create an observer instance
var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
  mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
    console.info("EVENT TRIGGERT " + mutation.target.id);
  });    
});
 
// configuration of the observer:
var config = { attributes: true, childList: true, characterData: true };
 
// pass in the target node, as well as the observer options
observer.observe(target, config);

// simulate the Change of the text value of span
function simulateChange(){
    target.innerText = "CHANGE";
}

setTimeout(simulateChange, 2000);
```

```html
<span id="user-location"></span>
```

If you want / have to use **jQuery** you could do this:
*in this example I added a second `span` just to show how it could work*

```js
// Bind to the DOMSubtreeModified Event
$('.user-location').bind('DOMSubtreeModified', function(e) {
  console.info("EVENT TRIGGERT " + e.target.id);
});

// simulating the Change of the text value of span
function simulateChange(){
   $('.user-location').each(function(idx, element){
      element.innerText = "CHANGED " + idx;
   });
 }

setTimeout(simulateChange, 1000);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="firstSpan" class="user-location">Unchanged 0</span><br/>
<span id="secondSpan" class="user-location">Unchanged 1</span>
```

Answer (score 6):

Using Javascript MutationObserver

```
  //More Details https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver
 // select the target node
var target = document.querySelector('.user-location')
// create an observer instance
var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
  console.log($('.user-location').text());   
});
// configuration of the observer:
var config = { childList: true};
// pass in the target node, as well as the observer options
observer.observe(target, config);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `input` event :

Like this :

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(".user-location").on("input",function(){

        console.log("You change Span tag");

    })
})
```

Example :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            span {
                border: 1px solid #000;
                width: 200px;
                height: 20px;
                position: absolute;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <span class="user-location" contenteditable="true"> </span>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){

        $(".user-location").on("input",function(){

            console.log("You change Span tag");

        })
    })
    </script>
    </body>  
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Mutation API [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver)

```
// Select the node that will be observed for mutations
var targetNode = document.getElementById('some-id');

// Options for the observer (which mutations to observe)
var config = { attributes: true, childList: true };

// Callback function to execute when mutations are observed
var callback = function(mutationsList) {
    for(var mutation of mutationsList) {
        if (mutation.type == 'childList') {
            console.log('A child node has been added or removed.');
        }
        else if (mutation.type == 'attributes') {
            console.log('The ' + mutation.attributeName + ' attribute was modified.');
        }
    }
};

// Create an observer instance linked to the callback function
var observer = new MutationObserver(callback);

// Start observing the target node for configured mutations
observer.observe(targetNode, config);

// Later, you can stop observing
observer.disconnect();
```

Answer (score -3):

You can use `javascript` for that.

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <span class="user-location" onchange="myFunction()">
       <input type="text"> 
    </span>
    <script>
       function myFunction() {
          alert("work");
       }
    </script>
 </body>
  </html>
```

Hope it will help.

Comment: Well unfortunately it doesn't seem that the onchange alert happens with each onchange text insert. It only alerts when you click out of the box and change the focus to another element. I read that onchange actually doesn't work for span on another stackoverflow thread. Though I'd like to know how to make it work.

Comment: Will not work. What you're doing is fire the event on the input tag. Block elements do not accept onChange event.