# Change div css if span contain text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have one input and span. When I type in input value is passed to span. Now I want to hide other div/button or something if my span have specific value. My code don't work. What's wrong?

```js
$('#input').on('keyup', function(){
  $('#status').html($(this).val());
});

$('#status').on('change', function(){
        var status = $('#status').html();
        if (status == "OK") {
            $('#test').css("background", "red");
        } else {
            $('#test').css("background", "blue");
        }
    });
```

```css
#test {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="input">

<span id="status"></span>

<div id="test"></div>
```

Comment: See this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39221775/trigger-for-span-text-html-on-changed

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Trigger for span text/html on changed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39221775/trigger-for-span-text-html-on-changed)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of checking changes on span element, it is better to do this logic inside of input event listener. Something like this:

```
$('#input').on('keyup', function(){
    var val = this.value;

    $('#status').html(val);

    if (val == "OK") {
        $('#test').css("background", "red");
    } else {
        $('#test').css("background", "blue");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Liste the keyup event and change the background

```js
$('#input').on('keyup', function(){
  $('#status').html($(this).val());
  console.log($(this).val());
  if ($('#status').html() == "OK") {
      $('#test').css("background", "red");
  } else {
      $('#test').css("background", "blue");
  }
});
```

```css
#test {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="input">

<span id="status"></span>

<div id="test-container">
  <div id="test"></div>
</div>
```