# Can't build a html/css inline form

Tags: html, css, wordpress, forms

I'm trying to build an inline forum in wordpress with html and css. I have a problem because the form doesn't appear inline way but in a normal one,
here you find the codes:

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <title>newsletter</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="newsletter-subscribe">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="intro">
                <h2 class="text-center"><strong>SCATTARE FOTOGRAFIE, FARE VIDEO E POTER VIAGGIARE CON QUESTA PASSIONE</strong><br></h2>
                <p class="text-center">Come scattare le tue migliori fotografie, realizzare video che tutti ammireranno, crescere sui social lavorando con ciò che ami e milgiorando le tue tecniche </p>
            </div>
            <form class="form-inline" method="post" action="the link">

                  <div id="mc_embed_signup_scroll">
                    <div class="form-inline"><input class="form-control form-control-sm" type="text" placeholder="Il tuo nome..." name="FNAME" required=""><input class="form-control" type="email" name="EMAIL" placeholder="La tua migliore email..." required=""></div>
                    <div class="form-inline"><button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Subscribe </button></div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

and i have this CSS, i haven't included it in HTML because i'm in wordpress

```
h2{font-size:24px;font-weight:700;margin-bottom:25px;line-height:1.5;padding-top:0;margin-top:0;color:inherit}
.form-inline {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
    align-items: center; }
  .form-inline {
    flex-direction: column;
 }

.newsletter-subscribe
.intro{font-size:16px;max-width:500px;margin:0 auto 25px}.newsletter-subscribe
.intro p{margin-bottom:35px}
.newsletter-subscribe

.newsletter-subscribe
form .form-control{background:#eff1f4;border:none;border-radius:3px;box-shadow:none;outline:0;color:inherit;text-indent:9px;height:45px;margin-right:10px;min-width:250px}.newsletter-subscribe
```

That's what i see

[image]

Comment: Can you share what are you looking for exactly? `form doesn't appear inline way but in a normal one` what does this mean by the way?

Comment: yes, sorry. i've added it to the question

Comment: So you want all inputs and buttons shown up inline side by side?

Comment: it's exactly what i want

Comment: Well, I've just added a new answer to your question, if you have any other problem with it just let me know. Also please keep in mind if the answer suites you make sure you vote it up and mark it as an answer to help others to find their suitable answers in the community.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here we go to achieve this, you have to remove this piece of code from your styles:

```
.form-inline {
   flex-direction: column;
}
```

**Why though?**

Because `flex-direction: column;` will make every one of your div children as an independent row, and whole of them as a column. Like the one, you achieved earlier.

Then the next step to achieve and inline form inputs and buttons here is to move your `button` tag out of the independent division with the same class and wrap all of them into a single div just like this:

```
 <div class="form-inline">
    <input class="form-control form-control-sm" type="text" placeholder="Il tuo nome..." name="FNAME" required="">
    <input class="form-control" type="email" name="EMAIL" placeholder="La tua migliore email..." required="">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Subscribe</button>
 </div>
```

**The final cut**

At the end all of your code will be something like the below snippet:

```css
h2 {
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: 700;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
  line-height: 1.5;
  padding-top: 0;
  margin-top: 0;
  color: inherit;
}

.form-inline {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.newsletter-subscribe .intro {
  font-size: 16px;
  max-width: 500px;
  margin: 0 auto 25px;
}

.newsletter-subscribe .intro p {
  margin-bottom: 35px;
}

.newsletter-subscribe .newsletter-subscribe form .form-control {
  background: #eff1f4;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 3px;
  box-shadow: none;
  outline: 0;
  color: inherit;
  text-indent: 9px;
  height: 45px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  min-width: 250px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <title>newsletter</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="newsletter-subscribe">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="intro">
        <h2 class="text-center"><strong>SCATTARE FOTOGRAFIE, FARE VIDEO E POTER VIAGGIARE CON QUESTA PASSIONE</strong><br></h2>
        <p class="text-center">Come scattare le tue migliori fotografie, realizzare video che tutti ammireranno, crescere sui social lavorando con ciò che ami e milgiorando le tue tecniche </p>
      </div>
      <form class="form-inline" method="post" action="the link">

        <div id="mc_embed_signup_scroll">
          <div class="form-inline">
            <input class="form-control form-control-sm" type="text" placeholder="Il tuo nome..." name="FNAME" required="">
            <input class="form-control" type="email" name="EMAIL" placeholder="La tua migliore email..." required="">
            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Subscribe </button>
          </div>
      </form>
      </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

**UPDATE**

So to make space between these inputs you should add `margin` property to each of div children, just like below:

```
.form-inline input, .form-inline button {
   margin: 0 5px;
}
```

Then the final output will be like this:

```css
h2 {
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: 700;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
  line-height: 1.5;
  padding-top: 0;
  margin-top: 0;
  color: inherit;
}

.form-inline {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.form-inline input, .form-inline button {
  margin: 0 5px;
}

.newsletter-subscribe .intro {
  font-size: 16px;
  max-width: 500px;
  margin: 0 auto 25px;
}

.newsletter-subscribe .intro p {
  margin-bottom: 35px;
}

.newsletter-subscribe .newsletter-subscribe form .form-control {
  background: #eff1f4;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 3px;
  box-shadow: none;
  outline: 0;
  color: inherit;
  text-indent: 9px;
  height: 45px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  min-width: 250px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <title>newsletter</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="newsletter-subscribe">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="intro">
        <h2 class="text-center"><strong>SCATTARE FOTOGRAFIE, FARE VIDEO E POTER VIAGGIARE CON QUESTA PASSIONE</strong><br></h2>
        <p class="text-center">Come scattare le tue migliori fotografie, realizzare video che tutti ammireranno, crescere sui social lavorando con ciò che ami e milgiorando le tue tecniche </p>
      </div>
      <form class="form-inline" method="post" action="the link">

        <div id="mc_embed_signup_scroll">
          <div class="form-inline">
            <input class="form-control form-control-sm" type="text" placeholder="Il tuo nome..." name="FNAME" required="">
            <input class="form-control" type="email" name="EMAIL" placeholder="La tua migliore email..." required="">
            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Subscribe </button>
          </div>
      </form>
      </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

**NOTE:** The property `margin` is shorthanded for `margin: /*margin-top margin-right margin-bottom margin-left*/` so if you use it like this: `margin: 0 5px` the top and bottom margins will be 0 and the right and left margins will be 5px.

Comment: Thank you so much, this help me a lot and now the from is this [link](https://imgur.com/QBPmXUk). another question (sorry, i've just started with css) how can i outdistance, so create a space from one block to the other? thanks.

Comment: I have find the code in this thread [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47798027/change-mailchimps-success-error-message) but i don't understand what the user intends for target node

Comment: @leoleoleoleo Dude, what's happening here? The thread you mentioned is something else and talks about error and success messages? Are you trying to implement it?