# How to listen content change in <span>?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a `<span>` element which holds some content in it. The content changes when you type something. How can I listen to those events?

For Example :

```
<span> Start content </span>
```

After some content change

```
<span> Changed content </span>
```

Is there any way I can listen to the key events (like keyup, blur)?

Comment: How does the content change _"when you type something"?_ This isn't natural behavior - do you have something like `contenteditable` on the span or an input with an attached event?

Comment: `<span>` is a static element. You're not supposed to be able to type anything in it, it's not an `<input>`. How do you achieve this?

Answer (score 6):

You can listen out for the `DOMSubtreeModified` event.

However, this doesn't sound like a good idea. You said:

> Is there any way I can listen to the key events (like keyup, blur)?

You should use a call this code next to the code where you change the content of the span. Otherwise, you should be using an input element to listen out to the events you listed.

Here is an example using the `DOMSubtreeModified` event:

```js
const content = document.getElementById('content')
const append = () => content.innerText += ' change'

content.addEventListener('DOMSubtreeModified', () => console.log('change'))
```

```html
<span id="content">Content</span>
<br>
<button onclick="append()">Change content</button>
```

Here are examples using `change` (which acts similarly to `blur`, but only triggers if there's a change) and `keypress` events:

```js
const content = document.getElementById('content')

content.addEventListener('change', () => console.log('change'))
content.addEventListener('keypress', () => console.log('keyPress'))
```

```html
<input type="text" id="content" value="Content">
```

Comment: DOMSubtreeModified support is deprecated in major browser (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationEvent). MutationObserver should be used instead.

Answer (score 1):

you can use **DOMSubtreeModified** to track changes on your span element. Refer the below question for further assistance,

[Trigger for span text/html on changed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39221775)

Answer (score 0):

To do this you should use a Mutation observer (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver). You would do something along those lines:

```
let observer = new MutationObserver((list, obs) => {
    console.log('Something has changed!')
})
let targetSpanElement = document.querySelector('span'); // use what selector works for you!
observer.observe(targetSpanElement, {
  characterData: true,
  childList: true,
  subtree: true
})
```