# How to detect text change inside a span

Tags: javascript, html, events

There is a `span` element but change text by button click
I want to detect text change by another function and show alert
But it not work

Here is my code:

```
    <Span class="spn">Span</Span>
    <button onclick="changespan()">click</button>
```

```
    <script>   
        function eventp() {
            $('.spn').on('change', () => alert('detect span text change.'))
          }

        function changespan() {
            $('.spn').text("span text changed.");
            eventp();

        }
    </script>
```

Comment: there's always [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Trigger for span text/html on changed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39221775/trigger-for-span-text-html-on-changed)

Answer (score 0):

`span` doesn't support the `change`-event. try this:

```js
function eventp() {
  $('.spn').on('DOMSubtreeModified', () => console.log('Detect span text change.'));
}

function changespan() {
  $('.spn').text("Span text changed.");
  eventp();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="spn">Span</span>
<button onclick="changespan()">click</button>
```

Comment: Did you test this? The event doesn't get triggered (properly) on the first change

Answer (score -1):

HTML

```html
<span id="spn"></span>
```

JS :

```js
const span = document.getElementById("spn")
span.addEventListener("change", function(){
   let value = span.innerText
   // Your code
})
```

Comment: Why would using an id over a class solve this?

Comment: what are you saying ? I used only the ID, and I am using ID for example, they can change it to be for class

Comment: I'm saying this answer is identical to what OP actually posted, but instead of using a class you are using an id. So how does this solve the question? Did you actually test your answer?

Answer (score -1):

try use id="spn" instead of class="spn"

```
    <span id="spn">Span</span>
    <button onclick="changespan()">click</button>
```

and use id instead class

```
    <script>   

function changespan() {
  document.querySelector('#spn').innerHTML = "span text changed."
  eventp();

}
    </script>
```

and try to MutationObserver instead to detect innerHtml change.

Comment: Why would using an id over a class solve this?