# how to get value from specific css class using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, wkwebview

Below is countdown timer.
is it possible get value "1:32" every time the value update using javascript from a html which contain below

```
01:32
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Using `getElementsByClassName` and `querySelector`. Note that `getElementsByClassName` return a list so is neccesary access to the first list position.

```js
var text = document.getElementsByClassName("myClass")[0].innerHTML; 
console.log(text)

text = document.querySelector(".myClass").innerHTML
console.log(text)
```

```html
<span class = myClass>text</span>
```

Also, I've used `class` but you can use other value to match with your html element.

Comment: is it possible to make this javascript get called upon value change on this class everytime ?

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10958529/how-to-handle-change-text-of-span) question in case it helps you

Comment: Wondering how using `innerHTML` would be any better than using `textContent` or `innerText` here!!!

Answer (score 3):

You can select the element using `document.querySelectorAll` and get the value inside span tag using `innerHTML` as follows.

```
document.querySelectorAll("[data-reactid='.1.0.0.0.1.0']").innerHTML
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use either:

> `getAttribute()` method of the Element interface returns the value of a
> specified attribute on the element.

```
var badgeTimer = document.querySelector('.vsm-badge-timer');
let reacid=badgeTimer.getAttribute('data-reacid');
```

> The dataset property on the `HTMLElement` interface provides read/write access to all the custom data attributes
> (data-*) set on the element. This access is available both in HTML and
> within the DOM.

```
var badgeTimer = document.querySelector('.vsm-badge-timer');
let reacid=badgeTimer.dataset['reacid'];
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get the first element's text of the class then you can try the following:

```
var data = document.querySelector('span.vsm-badge-timer').textContent;
```

If you have multiple elements with the class then you have get all the elements using `querySelectorAll()` and iterate them to take the value individually:

```
var all = document.querySelectorAll('span.vsm-badge-timer');
all.forEach(function(el){
  var data = el.textContent;
});
```